# Detect imbrication of date events in r

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to transforme df1 in df2 by defining an order of imbrication: 
 When an event of type A contain between in indate and outdate, one or more events of type B, then create a timeline for capturing each A-B events.

Do you have any ideas orther than dplyr::leftjoin ?

```
#INPUT
type = c("A","B","B","B")
startdate <- as.Date(c('2010-1-10','2010-1-12','2010-1-14','2010-2-5'))
outdate = as.Date(c('2010-1-30','2010-1-20','2010-1-25','2010-2-5'))
input = data.frame(type,startdate,outdate)
#OUTPUT
timeline = c("1","1","2","2","3")
type = c("A","B","A","B","B")
startdate1 = as.Date(c('2010-1-10','2010-1-12','2010-1-10','2010-1-14','2010-2-5'))
outdate1 <- as.Date(c('2010-1-30','2010-1-20','2010-1-30','2010-1-25','2010-2-5'))
output = data.frame(type,startdate1,outdate1,timeline)
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "imbrication". Are you referring to overlap? Can you edit your post to include your expected outcome?

Comment: Yes if there is an overlap of a type B events over a type A event.

Comment: Can you add expected output

Comment: it's already added, and you can see the new column added to the output is timeline.

Comment: I don't understand the logic behind your output. Dates in rows 2 and 3 of `input` overlap with the start/end dates in row 1. But in your `output` row 2 belongs to `timeline = 1` while row 3 belongs to `timeline = 2`. Why?

Comment: Because i want to separate each events of consecutive types A-B so if I have in input A-B-B-B with the three B events in overlap with A, then my output will give me three timelines